# Is there any onDocumentChange event?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events

Is there any event in Internet Explorer, that is fired whenever DOM is changed? For example:

```
document.attachEvent("ondocumentchange", function () {
    alert("you've just changed DOM!");
});
```

And when I execute:

```
document.appendChild(document.createElement("img"));
```

Window with text "you've just changed DOM!" appears.

I try to emulate "advanced" CSS selectors (e.g. +, >, [attr]) in IE6 using Javascript. However to work properly with dynamic content, they would have to be recalculated after each change in document.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Brute-force "solution":

```
(function (previousInnerHTML) {
    return function () {
        if (document.body.innerHTML !== previousInnerHTML) {
            alert("you've just (at max 33ms ago) changed DOM");
        }
        setTimout(arguments.callee, 33);
    };
})(document.body.innerHTML)();
```

Comment: Why would you use a setTimeout?  In this case wouldn't a setInterval make more sense?

Comment: Should anyone else stumble across this old post, as of IE 11 we have the option of mutationObserver https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#

Answer (score 3):

You want to look at dom mutation events - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_Events, and scroll down to the section on mutation events.  Only problem is that support for these events is pretty sketchy, so be careful using them.  Notably, a lack of support at all in IE or Opera.  Firefox, Safari and Chrome seem to be the only ones.

Something like:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function () {
    alert("you've just changed DOM!");
});
```

According to http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html for these kind of events you need to use addEventListener, not attachEvent.
The event apparently bubbles, so that should be fine.

Comment: "[…] lack of support at all in IE […]" – that's the problem – I need this event because of IE.

Comment: Afraid I don't think there is a way of doing it then, at least not without recursing over the DOM tree manually.  Can you not narrow down the changes to a specific child node?

Comment: Mutation events have been deprecated, mutationObserver is available as of IE 11 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, this *might* work:

```
document.body.attachEvent('onpropertychange', function(event) {
  if (event.propertyName !== 'innerHTML') return;
  alert("you've just changed DOM!");
});
```

This relies on IE's proprietary [onPropertyChange event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536956(VS.85).aspx) — since the document's `innerHTML` would change whenever a node is inserted. But:

1. It might not work with certain types of properties. I imagine `innerHTML` would function like a "getter" in that it'd only get recalculated when retrieved.
2. It would also pick up *a lot* of false positives — lots of other things would modify the `innerHTML` that would have nothing to do with node insertion. You could mitigate this by listening on a particular element, rather than document-wide.

Comment: Unfortunately, "Changing the `innerText` or `innerHTML` of child elements will not cause the __onpropertychange__ event to fire for the parent element," says the documentation. And even when function is attached to every DOM element, it is not called if I use DOM manipulation functions – only if innerHTML is changed directly.