# How can i trace changes made to the DOM by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

I have a large website in development with a large amount of JS in different files. I have come across an issue where something is removing a class from the DOM. I can see it when I view source but not in Firebug.

Normally I would place some alerts/console.log calls with the hasClass value but because I have no idea where to start I wanted to know if I can trace the change back when it occurs somehow?

Denis

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648996/how-do-i-monitor-the-dom-for-changes

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218445/is-there-any-ondocumentchange-event (specific to IE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebug lets you [set a breakpoint and single-step through your code](http://getfirebug.com/js.html). This should make it clear where the issue is happening.

Comment: That would mean stepping through every line of each JS file? If so it's not practical.

Answer (score 0):

that specific class name must be in use in that hidden function that remove it, right?
so either `grep` for it on posix-based system, or, if you are using Win system, use your IDE "search-in-files" function to trace that modification.

Comment: a friend of mine (http://intellectronica.net/) just sent me a comment on this one (at friendfeed)
here is what he says:
in YUI3, every attribute of every object has a corresponding change event, so you can just create a handler for the change event of the class attribute, put a breakpoint there and examine the stack trace. It's such a brilliant idea, they should adopt it as a standard for the DOM.