# Cannot listen document resize event

Tags: javascript, resize, document

I want to listen the event whenever the document(body) *size* changed
which would caused by anything inside 
(but you are assumed do not know what element caused the resize)

as the code below:
http://jsfiddle.net/marstone/7zaRT/8/

you can click the green area to change the div size, then the document.body resized.
however, the onresize event won't be fired.

I found that it only works when the window resizes, such as drag/maximum the browser window

any workaround? any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(e) {
alert("Bazinga!");
console.log(e);
​});​
```

Note however, that it tends to fire excessively, but I'll leave it to you to figure the how this could fit into your app.

http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/7zaRT/12/

Comment: The only way in IE is a crude way: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1218445/476786
Where you constantly poll your `DOM` to check for changes. You may be able to hack this to detect a change in viewport size. Try experimenting with Scrollbars and their relative position changes.

Oh, and if this answer has helped, please mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 2):

Resize events are available only on windows objects, as you said. You can use the [jquery-resize plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/) to add resize events on DOM elements, but be advice that they implement polling mechanisms to keep track of element's sizes. Due to that, you must always bind the event to the element you want to watch (delegate does not work as no real event is bubbled on the DOM).

So far I've used that plugin a couple of times, without any glitch. I'm not aware if other plugins implement this very same mechanism, but I'm somewhat sure that they all rely on a polling mechanism as this one.

Comment: thanks! but my project can not use jquery for some reason. i'd implement this mechanism myself. i wanna to find some light-weighted solution