# Jquery does not appear to work in IE7 only

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7

I have written JQuery that adds a CSS attribute to a button when it detectes an element with a specific CSS class: (in this case, when a validation div is displayed on a page)

```
  <script>
        $(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function () 
        {
            if ($('.errors').length)
            {
            alert('test');
            }
        });
    </script>
```

The alert is displayed in every browser (including IE8 and 9) but not IE7 - is this a known issue? Does anyone know of an alternative that could be used?

**Edit:** I have discovered IE7 can't execute '`DOMSubtreeModified`'. And I can see there are alternatives but the javascript needs to be called automatically and detect when a change has occurred, and not executing it using a call to a function. Any suggestions?

**Another Edit:** As it's a .NET MVC website, I can't see how to add a javascript call to the validation binding. Is there a way for javascript to detect changes on the whole page? i.e javascript code that can do the same as the above code?

Comment: IE7 doesn't support  `DOMSubtreeModified` event.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218445/is-there-any-ondocumentchange-event

Comment: My javascript needs to run when an element is displayed on the screen which is only displayed when there is a validation error. How can I make the javascript function get called automatically i.e if there's a change on in html? The link to the other question appears to require the function to be called.

Comment: Check this - http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMSubtreeModified   - the DOMSubtreeModified event type is defined in this specification for reference and completeness, but this specification deprecates the use of this event type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it only gets called when there's a validation error, then why use such a broad event as DOMSubtreeModified? I would use a custom event like this:

```
function validate() { 
  var error = false;
  //....
  //your validation code that finds an error
  if(error) {
    $(document).trigger('validationError');
  }
  //.....
}


$(document).on('validationError',function() {
   //your code that does something when an error is found
});
```

Comment: As it's a .NET MVC website, I can't see how to add a javascript call to the validation binding. Is there a way for javascript to detect changes on the whole page? i.e an equivalent to the code I posted in my question?

Comment: If you are using DOMSubtreeModified - then the validation MUST be performed using JavaScript as that is the only thing that can modify the DOM without reloading the page - wherever the code is that modifies the DOM (by creating/appending/modifying) <div class="errors">...</div> - that's where you trigger the event....I don't see how .NET MVC has anything to do with it.