# Is there an onmove equivalent for other browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

Long story short, I need to track when the size of the document changes.  Like if an expandable div is toggled.

In IE I'm able to use the onmove event of the documentelement, but I can't find anyway to do this in any other browser since onmove is specific to IE.

Any suggestions?

Before anybody asks... no, I can't just attach to the toggle event.

Oh and I can't use jquery or any other library (even longer story).

Thanks!

Edit: Looks like onmove doesn't work in ie9.  Is there a better way to handle this event?

Answer (score 0):

One pretty primitive way would be to poll for document changes and check the size. Take a look at this: [stackoverflow.com/questions/1218445/is-there-any-ondocumentchange-event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218445/is-there-any-ondocumentchange-event)